# How can I fine tune the spacing between the question and the start of the question's text in an exam environment

Tags: exam

I want to make questions in my exams, some of which just ask a question, some have an intro then parts, and then others launch straight into parts.

If I use the following:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt,a4]{exam}  
\usepackage{mathptmx}  
\qformat{\textbf{\thequestion .} \hspace{0.2cm} \slshape [Maximum mark: \thepoints] \hfill}  
% \renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\parsep}{4mm}} I'm not using this bit but I know %   
% how to adjust the space to the parts %  
\begin{document}  
  Blah blah blah...  
  \begin{questions}  
    \question[3]  
      This question has got quite a wordy introduction that may spill over onto a second or even   
      a higher number of successive lines all chock full of vital information.  
      \newline Given that this question has some parts, how would you:  
      \begin{parts}  
        \part Answer this. \hfill \textit{[1 mark]}  
        \part Answer that. \hfill \textit{[2 marks]}  
      \end{parts}  
    \question[16]  
      \begin{parts}  
        \part This question doesn't have an intro so just answer it. \hfill   \textit{[1 mark]}  
        \part And then answer this bit. \hfill \textit{[15 marks]}  
      \end{parts}  
    \question[2]  
      This one is dead easy, so just answer it.  
  \end{questions}  
  \end{document}
```

Then I don't like the horizontal spacing.  If you compare the distance from the [Maximum mark:...] to the text in the intro-ed and non-parted questions (1 & 3) to the distance in question 2, it differs.  I want to be able to make the distance increase for questions like 1 & 3 to at least the same as in Q2, or even better to a distance of my choosing.

I can do it by changing the line spacing, but then the multiple lines of text in Q1's introduction become similarly spaced out - again, not what I want.

I want control over *just* the spacing from points to the questions.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Thi may be close to what you are looking for.  I added a rule (`\mystrut`) to the `\qformat` definition.  The trouble is that the `parts` environment adds extra space of its own volition.  I tried to nullify that somewhat with a negative `\vspace` when `parts` is invoked.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt,a4]{exam}  
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\def\mystrut{\protect\rule[-2.2ex]{0ex}{2.2ex}} 
\qformat{\textbf{\thequestion .} \hspace{0.2cm} \slshape [Maximum mark: \thepoints]\mystrut\hfill}  
\let\svparts\parts
\def\parts{\svparts\vspace{-.5ex}}
% \renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\parsep}{4mm}} I'm not using this bit but I know %   
% how to adjust the space to the parts %  
\begin{document}  
  Blah blah blah...  
  \begin{questions}  
    \question[3]  
      This question has got quite a wordy introduction that may spill over onto a second or even   
      a higher number of successive lines all chock full of vital information.  
      \newline Given that this question has some parts, how would you:  
      \begin{parts}  
        \part Answer this. \hfill \textit{[1 mark]}  
        \part Answer that. \hfill \textit{[2 marks]}  
      \end{parts}  
    \question[16]  
      \begin{parts}  
        \part This question doesn't have an intro so just answer it. \hfill   \textit{[1 mark]}  
        \part And then answer this bit. \hfill \textit{[15 marks]}  
      \end{parts}  
    \question[2]  
      This one is dead easy, so just answer it.  
  \end{questions}  
  \end{document}
```

[image]